# web3 v1 beta. estimateGas throwing Transaction execution error

Tags: web3js, nodejs, gas-estimate

I am using `web3` verion 1 (beta) connected to a remote Parity node via websocket.

There is a deployed contract `TestContract` with a `test` function that emits a `Tested` event that simply echoes back `msg.sender`.

```
contract TestContract {
    event Tested(address sender);

    function test() {
      require(msg.sender != 0x0);
      Tested(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

The following code

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(testContactAbi, theAddress)
const gasNeeded = await contract.methods.test().estimateGas({ from: SENDER_ADDRESS })
console.log('gasNeeded', gasNeeded)
```

throws `Transaction execution error`

I am sure I have a connection to the node

```
const listening = await web3.eth.net.isListening()
```

listening is `true`

How would I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out the issue.  I'd forgotten to `export` the `SENDER_ADDRESS` from my `constants.js` file.  Sigh. Now the address is not `undefined` it works.  My bad.